# Is hacking and stealing punished more harshly than solely hacking?

Tags: criminal-law, theft

Which of the following crimes generally has a more severe punishment:

- Unauthorized bank account access (e.g. hacking in to view information), or
- Unauthorized account access *and* taking money from that account

Comment: Is making an illegal lane change while speeding punished more harshly than solely making an illegal lane change?

Answer (score 3):

The latter because there are two crimes involved (hacking *and* stealing) and you would get punished for both.